# Why am I suddenly not getting content from the Blogger API?

Tags: javascript, json, google-api, blogger

I have been using the Google API to get JSON data from my Blogger account and display and format blog posts on my own webiste.

It was working perfectly for weeks, and then suddenly, as of yesterday, the `content` stops displaying. The `title`, `update` (the date the post was updated), and the `id`, all come back just as they always have. Only the `content` stopped coming back.

I haven't changed the code in any way since first implementing it, and I looked for documentation to see if the API had changed, but didn't come across anything. So I am completely stumped as to why this one aspect of the code would suddenly stop working.

This is pretty much the entire Javascript that I use to get the JSON data. Is there something wroing with it?

```
function init() {
    // Get your API key from http://code.google.com/apis/console
    gapi.client.setApiKey('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
    // Load the Blogger JSON API
    gapi.client.load('blogger', 'v3', function() {
        // Load the list of posts for code.blogger.com
        var request = gapi.client.blogger.posts.list({
            'blogId': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            'fields': 'items(content,title,updated,id)'
        });
        request.execute(function(response) {
            var blogger = document.getElementById("blogger");
            var anchor = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < response.items.length; i++)
            {
                var bloggerDiv = document.createElement("div");
                bloggerDiv.id = "blogger-" + i;
                bloggerDiv.className = "bloggerItem";
                $(bloggerDiv).append("<h2>" + response.items[i].title + "</h2>");
                var date = response.items[i].updated;
                date = date.replace("T", " ");
                date = date.replace("+09:00", "");
                var printDate = new moment(date);
                $(bloggerDiv).append("<p><span class='byline'>" + printDate.format('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a') + "</span></p>");
                $(bloggerDiv).append(response.items[i].content)
                bloggerAnchor = document.createElement("a");
                bloggerAnchor.name = "blogger-" + response.items[i].id;
                blogger.appendChild(bloggerAnchor);
                blogger.appendChild(bloggerDiv);
                anchor = anchor + 1;
            }
            // find out which anchor the user wanted...
            var hashVal = window.location.hash.substr(1);
// ... then jump to that position:
            location.hash = "#" + hashVal;
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now fetchBodies defaults is false instead of true. For this reason you need to add param fetchBodies=true.

Comment: Where was this announced? I'm concerned that there will be future changes without warning that break my functionality.

Comment: I have just tried yesterday that on my blog but don't exist official documentation about that. I suppose is a bug or a new release not documented.